# Combining excel workbooks with same header columns but various rows in a master wb

Tags: excel, powerquery

Hello I am trying to create a 'master' sheet that houses data from 4 workbooks. All four workbooks have the same headers but they are for different regions. I.E data for the east,west,north and south. Each workbook has a different amount of rows. I want to automate the process of combining the documents into one.

I tried power query but i'm not a expert.

Comment: One option is to create linked tables in Access to your 4 workbooks. Then you can easily combine them with a union query and send the results back out to a master workbook.

Comment: https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/consolidate-multiple-excel-workbooks-using-power-query/

Comment: https://trumpexcel.com/combine-data-from-multiple-workbooks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps in Power Query:

- in a new workbook, create a query to each of the four workbooks
- add a column for the region with the formula `="Region A` (adjust the region name accordingly.
- load the queries as connections only, not to a worksheet
- in one of the four queries, append the other three.
- load that one to a worksheet.